# access value from async method to onCreate()

Tags: android

Hi I just want to access the string value that get from the api , into the onCreate method. I post my code below. In the getName class i get the name properly but i can't access the value in the oncreate method.I want to set the name as the Welcome Admin like that. I tried this code in the getName class but it call two times so that it display two times in the navigation drawer. To avoid this I just want to access the string value in the onCreate method. Thank you in advance.

```
    package com.abc;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.R.*;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.BaseBundle;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class navigation_drawer_class extends Activity
    {
    private static final int Copy = 0;
    int a =0;
    public static FrameLayout frameLayout;
    TextView mytextview;
    public static ListView mDrawerList;
    public static String Fullname;
    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    String str_Data="";
    protected String[] listArray = {"A","B","C","D ","E","F"," G"};
    protected static int position;
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;

    JSONObject post_details_obj,post_obj;

    public static String FIRST_NAME="first_name",LAST_NAME="last_name",PROFILE_IMAGE="image_name";
    JSONArray staff_data_array;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Operation op=new Operation();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //------------------ THIS ONE -------------------------
    getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.crop3);//THIS ONE FOR THE DRAWER LOGO
    //--------------------- THIS ONE ----------------------

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray));

    new getname.execute();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id)
    {
    position -= mDrawerList.getHeaderViewsCount();//THIS ONE FOR THE FIRST ITEM AS TITLE

    openActivity(position);
    }


    });
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this,      // host Activity 
    mDrawerLayout,     // DrawerLayout object 
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,     // nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret 
    R.string.open_drawer,       // "open drawer" description for accessibility 
    R.string.close_drawer)      // "close drawer" description for accessibility 
    {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) 
    {
    getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
    {
    getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) 
    {
    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) 
    {
    super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
    }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    if(isLaunch){
    isLaunch = false;
    openActivity(0);

    }
    }

    protected void openActivity(int position) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    navigation_drawer_class.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class));

    break;


    default:


    break;
    }   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
    //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) 
    {
    return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList))
    {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    else 
    {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    }


    private class getname extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
    {
    Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() 
    {
    dialog = new Dialog(navigation_drawer_class.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
    dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

    String STAFF_URL=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"staff","get_staff_details","");
    staff_data_array = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(STAFF_URL+"&vis_encode=json",navigation_drawer_class.this);
    return staff_data_array;

    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(JSONArray staff_data_array) 
    {   
    super.onPostExecute(staff_data_array);
    String staff_data_result =staff_data_array.toString();

    try {
    post_obj = staff_data_array.getJSONObject(0);
    String fname=post_obj.getString(FIRST_NAME);
    String lname=post_obj.getString(LAST_NAME);
    String image=post_obj.getString(PROFILE_IMAGE);

    String fullname =fname;

    Fullname="Welcome "+fullname;


    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dialog.dismiss();
    }
    }



    }
```

Comment: You cannot access this from onCreate - you cannot assume that 'getname' task has completed. The only safe way is to set the value from onPostExecute of 'getname', only then you know you have the value. From there you should put the value where you want.

Comment: to access the string value at onCreate method is really bad idea because asyncTask will take some time to get execute and get the user name info. And you must be doing something wrong because as of the above code name is being stored in the variable only once.

Comment: @yakobom : how to set the value from onPostExecute? can you give me an example. Bcoz I am new to android .

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you want is to add it to the mDrawerList, is that right? So that's what you need to do. Do you have a problem accessing it?

Comment: Yes , I get the name from the api that is the staff name ....when he launch the app I just want to show "Welcome Staff".I write the code in getname class it works but problem is that it shows two times.

Comment: I just added the following code to show the name  : View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerview_nav_drawer,null);
           TextView headerValue = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerview_id);
           headerValue.setText(Fullname);
           
           headerValue.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.default_img,0,0,0);
           mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headerValue, null, false);

Comment: OK, so you should call this code when the tasks ends (onPostExecute) and it should work. If it happens twice, you must be calling the task twice somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I just call getname method in openActivity() .Please check the comment like //THIS ONE and it works for me.

```
    package com.abc;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.R.*;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.BaseBundle;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class navigation_drawer_class extends Activity
    {
    private static final int Copy = 0;
    int a =0;
    public static FrameLayout frameLayout;
    TextView mytextview;
    public static ListView mDrawerList;
    public static String Fullname;
    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    String str_Data="";
    protected String[] listArray = {"A","B","C","D ","E","F"," G"};
    protected static int position;
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;

    JSONObject post_details_obj,post_obj;

    public static String FIRST_NAME="first_name",LAST_NAME="last_name",PROFILE_IMAGE="image_name";
    JSONArray staff_data_array;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Operation op=new Operation();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.crop3);


    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray));

    //new getname.execute(); //THIS ONE TO

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id)
    {
    position -= mDrawerList.getHeaderViewsCount();

    openActivity(position);
    }


    });
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this,      // host Activity 
    mDrawerLayout,     // DrawerLayout object 
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,     // nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret 
    R.string.open_drawer,       // "open drawer" description for accessibility 
    R.string.close_drawer)      // "close drawer" description for accessibility 
    {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) 
    {
    getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
    {
    getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) 
    {
    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) 
    {
    super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
    }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    if(isLaunch){
    isLaunch = false;
    openActivity(0);

    }
    }

    protected void openActivity(int position) {

        new getname.execute(); //THIS ONE Here


    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    navigation_drawer_class.position = position; 

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class));

    break;


    default:


    break;
    }   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) 
    {
    return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList))
    {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    else 
    {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    }


    private class getname extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
    {
    Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() 
    {
    dialog = new Dialog(navigation_drawer_class.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
    dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

    String STAFF_URL=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"staff","get_staff_details","");
    staff_data_array = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(STAFF_URL+"&vis_encode=json",navigation_drawer_class.this);
    return staff_data_array;

    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(JSONArray staff_data_array) 
    {   
    super.onPostExecute(staff_data_array);
    String staff_data_result =staff_data_array.toString();

    try {
    post_obj = staff_data_array.getJSONObject(0);
    String fname=post_obj.getString(FIRST_NAME);
    String lname=post_obj.getString(LAST_NAME);
    String image=post_obj.getString(PROFILE_IMAGE);

    String fullname =fname;

    Fullname="Welcome "+fullname;


    } catch (JSONException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dialog.dismiss();
    }
    }



    }
```